# Not able to connect to mysql running in a container from application

Tags: mysql, docker, go, kubernetes, docker-compose

I am trying to run SLTs and for that i have defined mysql as a dependency in my docker-compose.yml

```
  Platform:
    networks:
      - shared
    image: platform
    build:
      context: ../../../
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.slt
    container_name: platform
    ports:
      - 7777:7777
      - 1053:1053
    volumes:
      - /tmp/server:/tmp/server
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - docker.env
    depends_on:
      - predictiondb
predictiondb:
    networks:
      - shared
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: predictiondb
    environment:
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "prediction"
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
    volumes:
      - predictiondb:/var/lib/mysql
```

After running the docker-compose.yml i am trying to connect with the mysql using my application.

```
import (
"database/sql"

_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(localhost:3306)/prediction")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer db.Close()
err = db.ping()
if err != nil {
   log.Print(err)
}
```

Here i am getting the error

```
 {"error": "dial tcp 172.18.0.2:3306: connect: connection refused"}
```

1. I have checked that mysql is running in a container using docker ps command.
2. I have tried connecting with mysql from my local(mysql -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -p) on the port 3306 and able to connect and also able to see the prediction database created.
3. checked the logs of the container and mysql is running.
4. tried using root:root@tcp(predictiondb:3306)/prediction, but still same error.

mysql docker logs

```
2022-07-20T15:49:26.367485Z 11 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.29).
2022-07-20T15:49:27.706467Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-07-20 15:49:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped

2022-07-20 15:49:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2022-07-20T15:49:28.598959Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) starting as process 1
2022-07-20T15:49:28.606127Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-07-20T15:49:28.712782Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-07-20T15:49:28.928948Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-07-20T15:49:28.929033Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-07-20T15:49:28.931482Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2022-07-20T15:49:28.972456Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2022-07-20T15:49:28.972721Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

My application is running in another docker container, i am using same docker-compose.yml

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If your application runs within the same docker-compose, then you can use your container name as a host, e.g. `sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(predictiondb:3306)/prediction")`

Comment: @lub0v already tried, i have mentioned that as well.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Could you provide full `docker-compose.yaml` with both applications in the description and also what OS you're using.  Here's info on the docker-compose networking https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: instead of `localhost:3306`  try with `host.docker.internal:3306`

Comment: @lub0v added the full file in the question.

Comment: @ManjeetThakur getting {"error": "Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"}

Comment: @whishky what is "shared" networks? I think you didn't post the whole docker-compose? try removing the "networks" part in the compose file.  The `root:root@tcp(predictiondb:3306)/prediction` should work when you use same docker-compose file as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @whishky That is a different error but you can access using host.docker.internal

Comment: @lub0v 
networks:
  shared:
    external:
      name: shared
After removing this as well throwing same error.

Answer (score 0):

When your application is running in a container started by the same docker-compose file you cannot access the exposed port from localhost because it is visible only from the host, it cannot be accessed from another container. You need to connect to the wanted application through the container name:

```golang
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(predictiondb:3306)/prediction")
```

Comment: already tried not working, 4th point.